Cloud Run in Google Cloud doesn't recognize time.sleep() in my Python script
I have a Cloud Run service running a Python script in a Docker container.
Running the script on a VM in GCP or locally works fine. It recognizes the time.sleep() in my script.
But Cloud Run does not. What I have in my script is code for collecting data every 2 minutes because the data is updated every 2 minutes. And it is encapsulated in a while loop where if the loop takes 40 seconds then I set this to time.sleep(80).
But Cloud Run is not recognizing it and below are my service settings. Cloud Run doesn't sleep but immediately starts next iteration in the loop. Where as if it was local or on the VM it would sleep for 80 seconds per iteration and then continue to the next iteration.
Minimum service autoscaling instances = 0
Minimum revision autoscaling instances = 0
Maximum revision autoscaling instances = 1
Maximum concurrent requests per instances = Tried both 6 and 80

Any idea?

While I'm not a python dev/expert, I'm not able to answer it.
But I can tell you that your design is not optimal.
With Cloud Run, you pay for the resource that you use during request handling. If you wait actively, I mean, you sleep with CPU and memory reserved for your Cloud Run instance, you will pay for these resources. You will pay for doing nothing? Strange design!!
A better design is to use an external service, to wait for you. Cloud Scheduler is the best for this. Schedule your CRON expression to run it every 2 minutes */2 * * * * and invoke your Cloud Run service endpoint. Like that, you will pay the resource only every 2 minutes to process your data. The rest of the time, you will pay nothing. Better for your money, and for the planet.

And, by the way, it solves your time.sleep() issue, because you can remove it!

I guess you're right. The script was directly uploaded into the cloud and was not optimized for this design.
